# CKEditor does not transfer what is written to the database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, ckeditor

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<script src="../ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

This way I add it to my project in visual studio.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" runat="server" CssClass="texboxGorsel" name="textBox1"></asp:TextBox>
            <script>CKEDITOR.replace("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$textBox1")</script>
```

I throw CKeditor this way too. I run the project without any problems, but the information I wrote in CKeditor is not added to the database.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: first ensure that the error is on ckeditor and not on insert data to database, second use `<%=textBox1.ClientID %>` and not `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$textBox1` and final run the script on document ready.

Comment: CKEditor on it's own does not do anything with a database. You need to write code for that. If you've written some please share a [MCVE]

Comment: Look in the documentation for `getData()`